# InvalidArgumentException vs UnexpectedValueException

Tags: php, exception, spl

When should I use [InvalidArgumentException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) and when [UnexpectedValueException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)? They look the same to me.

[Note](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php#spl.exceptions.tree) that one extends LogicException and the other one extends RuntimeException, so the difference shouldn't be so subtle IMO.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking closely at the descriptions on the manual pages:

#### [InvalidArgumentException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php)

> Exception thrown if *an argument is not of the expected type*.

<sub>(The description was `Exception thrown if an argument does not match with the expected value.` [until mid-2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140119224439/https://www.php.net/invalidargumentexception), but was changed [when PHP 5.6 got introduced](https://web.archive.org/web/20140606205440/https://www.php.net:80/invalidargumentexception))</sub>

#### [UnexpectedValueException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)

> Exception thrown if *a value does not match with a set of values*. Typically this happens when a function calls another function and expects the return value to be of a certain type or value[,] not including arithmetic or buffer related errors.

From this, we can conclude that `InvalidArgumentException` is intended to *check types of arguments* passed to a function, while `UnexpectedValueException` is intended to *verify values vs valid value sets*, possibly during the internal computations of a function (e.g. values returned from other functions).

Note that checking the values of arguments is kind of gray area here; arguably, since `InvalidArgumentException extends LogicException`, it should only handle situations which [`should lead directly to a fix in your code.`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php#Introduction) Since throwing an exception in case of out-of-range input values can be a completely expected *runtime* behaviour, this leaves `UnexpectedValueException` (which extends `RuntimeException`) as the only candidate in such cases.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php
It says `type`, not value

Comment: @SiteTester: Looks like the manual page was updated sometime in April 2013, after this answer was posted. Earlier versions (https://web.archive.org/web/20130317022714/http://php.net/InvalidArgumentException) had "value".

Comment: @outis FWIW, pre-5.6 docs actually had a completely different, and IMVHO equally confusing/unclear wording. A real pity we still don't have a clear, extensive and well-documented set of common exceptions in SPL as of 2019...

Answer (score 20):

I guess the largest difference is "argument" vs "value".

The way I see it is that `InvalidArgumentException` is for (passed) *arguments*, whereas `UnexpectedValueException` applies to (returned) *values*. 
Also there's a subtle but important difference between "invalid" and "unexpected" - which also explains why the first is LogicException and the second a RuntimeException.

For example: say i've got a function that utilizes the Twitter-api called: `getLastMessageDate($userid)`: 
You pass a (numeric) user-id and it returns the date of the last message of that user as yyyy-mm-dd string.

Now, suppose I call this function with a string as argument instead of a number. At this point I can call an InvalidArgumentException, because the provided argument is invalid for this function.
These checks can be done by *logic* - because a variable is either numeric or it is not. Therefore it's a LogicException.

However, the *return value* of a function may not be verifiable by logic - especially when you're dealing with (third-party) dynamic content. Because you can never know exactly what your function is going to return. (if you would, this would arguably render your function useless.)

So, this time I call my function with a (valid) user-id and my function gets the date of the last message of that user. With this date I would like to do something, like some formatting.

Now imagine the guys at Twitter did something wrong and instead of my *expected*  yyyy-mm-dd date-string, I get an empty string or a different string saying 'blaaaa'.
At this point, i can throw an `UnexpectedValueException`.

I can't say that this value is "Invalid" - I asked for a string and I got a string. But it is however not the "kind of string" i was expecting: therefore **Unexpected** ValueException.

Hope this clears something up. This is my first post - so far I've learned that writing down what's in my head isn't the easiest thing (also English is not my native language).

Comment: _italic_ _"At this point I can call an InvalidArgumentException, because the provided argument is invalid for this function"_

You could also throw an UnexpectedValueException as you were expecting an integer but got an unexpected type (string).

Answer (score 15):

My understanding is that `InvalidArgumentException`, being a [`LogicException`](http://php.net/class.logicexception), should be used if you check an argument against a fixed list of possible value ranges. For example, checking if user entered data contains only numbers. The program *logic* can be expected to handle these value ranges.

`UnexpectedValueException`, being a [`RuntimeException`](http://php.net/class.runtimeexception) (*errors that can only be found on runtime / cannot be detected at compile time*), would be used for Exceptions that occur outside of foreseeable and specified input ranges (possibly as a last resort after the "logic" checks above).

The key to answering this question might be the `Unexpected...` in `UnexpectedValueException`. `Unexpected` means there is no handling for this value in the program logic. `Invalid`, on the other hand, suggests that this value has been handled.

Comment: +1.  I typically find myself using `UnexpectedValueExpection` in the `default` case of `switch` statements (e.g. for the state in a FSM), which are supposed to handle a finite set of possible values.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, If the switched variable is derived from an argument though, you should also add an `InvalidArgumentException` check above the `switch` statement.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I think a `DomainException` would be even more suitable for that.

Comment: +0 - the docs clearly say (and the change made the things even clearer) that IAEx is about *type*, not *value*. A such, doing a check vs *a fixed list of possible value ranges* is an ab-use of this exception ATM.