# How to make the switch statement more accurate?

Tags: java

We were ask to make a program using the switch statement..

Here is my code:

```
    double price = 0, totalPrice;

    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    int optionNumber = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

    switch(optionNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            price = 190.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            price = 410.00;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid number!");
            break;
    }

    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

    totalPrice = price * quantity;
```

So basically, the user will input a certain number and it will have different prices... inside the switch statements.
but if the user inputs a wrong number, it will display an error message and i dont want the user to enter the quantity which will be executed after the switch statement.
we are not allowed to use any methods or functions and i dont want to code repeatedly like this:

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    int optionNumber = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

    switch(optionNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            price = 190.00;
            System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
            totalPrice = price * quantity;
            System.out.print("Total price: " + totalPrice);
            break;
        case 2:
            price = 410.00;
            System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
            totalPrice = price * quantity;
            System.out.print("Total price: " + totalPrice);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid number!");
            break;
    }
```

is there any other way not to use if else, methods, functions or coding repeatedly?
ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED.

Comment: Perhaps just `return` when catching the `default` option?

Comment: You should use a loop probably.

Comment: when you say you don't want code "repeatedly" does that mean no loops?

Comment: I think he means he doesn't want duplicated code

Comment: You can never know, the OP doesn't want to use methods for some reason so it wouldn't surprise me if loops are out of the question also

Comment: another reasonable solution is to throw an exception in the default case

Comment: Do you want to: (a) repeatedly ask for input until the user get's it right;  (b) not ask for a quantity and then move on; or (c) exit the program entirely? You probably need to define your specification more clearly for your question in order to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag and make it false if invalid option is selected.
Then only ask user further if flag is true.

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
    int optionNumber = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
    boolean flag = true;
    switch (optionNumber) {
        case 1:
            price = 190.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            price = 410.00;
            break;
        default:
            flag = false;
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid number!");
            break;
    }
    if (flag) {
        System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
        totalPrice = price * quantity;
        System.out.print("Total price: " + totalPrice);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as this:

```
while(!valid option)
   //do this stuff
```

Use a **flag** and set it to true if the number entered is valid, so it will go to your next instruction; else ask again for input.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `default` from the `switch` statement and check to see if the price is equal to 0 after the `switch` statement

```
double price = 0, totalPrice;

System.out.print("Enter the number of your choice: ");
int optionNumber = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

switch(optionNumber)
{
    case 1:
        price = 190.00;
        break;
    case 2:
        price = 410.00;
        break;
}

if (price == 0)
{
     System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid number!");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
    totalPrice = price * quantity;
    System.out.print("Total price: " + totalPrice);
}
```

This keeps you from adding unnecessary variables (like a boolean flag) when you already have one (`price`) with a default value of `0` that you can check against.

Comment: Quoting the OP: _is there any other way not to use if else [...]_, `if else` is not an option (don't know why tough)

Comment: @Narmer I think he's talking about using `if/else` statements repeatedly, like inside every `case`.  That's how I understood the question anyway.  I would think a single `if/else` statement would be ok the way I read the question.  *"is there any other way not to use if else, methods, functions or coding **repeatedly***? "

Comment: I think that _repeatedly_ refers to _coding_ (as in _i dont want to code repeatedly like this_ written above that). This doesn't leave out the fact that the OP isn't completely clear on what she wants to do.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer dissipates all the doubts :D

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception

```
  default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid number!");
```

See also [InvalidArgumentException vs UnexpectedValueException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483667/invalidargumentexception-vs-unexpectedvalueexception)